# How to change custom Paper size in Crystal Reports in VS 2005?

Tags: crystal-reports, report

How to change custom Paper size in Crystal Reports in VS 2005 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the printer. You should be able to change the paper size of the printer the report is using to change the layout of the report. Try Page Setup to get to some of these settings.

Also, In Crystal Reports XI you can click on the Details section in the section expert and select the layout tab to the right to change a few settings such as Detail Width Size, Gap Between Details (Horizontal, Vertical) and Printing Direction. Hope this helps.